# Использование в новой форме значений из старой

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Есть 2 формы. На 1 форме датагридвью. В нем 3 колонки. На 2 форме датагрид с 1 колонкой. Каким образом можно выделенные значения 3 колонки из таблицы 1 формы заполнить в таблицу на 2 форме?
Вообщем сделал пока что кое-что по другому: в первой форме в массив записываю значения выбранных строк из 3 столбца. Во второй форме тоже самое. А вот как теперь в третьей таблице заполнить две колонки их значениями из массивов , которые в других формах ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ну, учитывая отсутствие деталей о архитектуре приложения и о том, как, кем и когда эти формы создаются то предложу вам такой вариант:

```
public static class Class1
    {
        public static /*Тут переменные/массивы в которых будут сохранятся данные из выбранных строк*/

    }
```

Соответственно доступ к полям этого класса вы можете получить из любой формы примерно следующим образом:

```
Class1.SomeValueName
```

А дальше уже добавляйте и оформляйте этот класс так как вам нужно. 
Применительно к вашей задаче после выбора элементов в первой таблице вы записываете их в один массив в этом классе, по выбору данных из второй таблицы делаете запись во второй массив. При открытии третей формы после инициализации компонентов считываете оба масива и заполняете полученными данными таблицу.